# How to put qrcode inside a cell in tabularx?

Tags: tabularx, qrcode

I am trying to put a qrcode inside the right column of a tabularx environment. The qrcode code outside of a tabularx works fine, but when I put the qrcode in a table cell, I get these errors:

```
Paragraph ended before \qrcode@in was complete \end{tabularx} 
Missing { inserted \end{tabularx}
```

I cannot find that missing opening bracket.

If I replace the \qrcode with simple text, the table renders nicely. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample tex file with what I've tried:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX} \\
Please transfer your money to our bank account, please see qrcode on the right & 
\qrcode[height=1.8cm]{BCD
002
2
SCT
SOLADEST600
Peter Frampton
DE1333q2387267
EUR171.36


Invoice 123 - Charles Mayer
} \\
\end{tabularx}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabularx` only partially supports verbatim material inside it, so the simplest thing is to typeset the QR-code in a box and use the box in the `tabularx` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\newsavebox{\qrcodebox}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{lrbox}{\qrcodebox}
\qrcode[height=1.8cm]{BCD
002
2
SCT
SOLADEST600
Peter Frampton
DE1333q2387267
EUR171.36


Invoice 123 - Charles Mayer
}\end{lrbox}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xc@{}} \\
Please transfer your money to our bank account, please see qrcode on the right & 
\usebox{\qrcodebox}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, egreg. Works very nicely.